# Display two UL elements side by side, centered vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

I've been struggling with this for a while and couldn't find the right solution.

At the bottom of the page I've a footer that's full width. Inside it I want to display I list of messages and right next to its left an icon, in this case it's a Font Awesome icon.
The message list needs to be centered both vertically and horizontally and the icon has to be centered vertically.

I've tried doing this using ul elements with display: inline-block and text-align: center. 
The messages displays correctly but the icon is stuck in the same place no matter the size of its container.

Here's what I've so far:

```
<div class="error-message-container">
  <ul class="error-message-bell">
    <li aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bell-slash-o"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="error-message-list">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.error-message-container {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        bottom: 0;
        color: light-blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
}

.error-message-container .error-message-bell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.error-message-container .error-message-list {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1rw80jz/1/

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Please see answer below.

Comment: Thanks Kelly but, at least for me, that fiddle output looks the same as the one I posted. I probably didn't explain myself correctly. What I was trying to achieve was to display the bell vertically centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only one icon, you can use pseudo-elements::before for the bell

```
.error-message-container {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        bottom: 0;
        color: light-blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
}

.error-message-container .error-message-list {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  position: relative; /** this provides reference to the ::before element **/
}

.error-message-list::before {
  content: "\f1f6"; /** refers to awesome font **/
  font-family: FontAwesome; /** refers to awesome font **/
  position: absolute; /** this will stick to error-message-list **/
  top: 50%; /** this will position the icon 50% height of the error-message-list **/
  margin-top: -10px; /** minus half the icon height to truely vertically centered **/
  left: -20px; /** this will push it to the left out the error-message-list **/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b1rw80jz/6/

Answer (score 1):

You could use flex-box like this:
+CSS

```
.error-message-container {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        bottom: 0;
        color: light-blue;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
}

.error-message-container .error-message-bell {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.error-message-container .error-message-list {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.center {
  display: -webkit-box; 
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: -ms-flexbox; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center; 
  -webkit-box-align: center; 
  align-items: center;
}
```

+HTML

```
<div class="error-message-container center">
  <ul class="error-message-bell center">
    <li aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bell-slash-o"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="error-message-list">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b1rw80jz/4/)

Comment: Thanks. This is actually a solution but in my case there seem to be other classes in the application that make it not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `line-height: 5; vertical-align: top;` to `.error-message-container .error-message-bell`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b1rw80jz/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the .error-message-list display to `block` and add `margin-bottom: -5px;` to .error-message-bell instead of margin-top

https://jsfiddle.net/b1rw80jz/3/

Answer (score 0):

Font-Awesome already does it for you by using the `<i>` element and nesting it within your `<li>`. Refer to [documentation](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list). BTW, I put a **DANGER!** icon in just for the hell of it.

```
   <li><i class="fa fa-bell-slash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ERROR!</li>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/2ek6t93z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="error-message-container">
  <div class="inner-container">
  <ul class="error-message-bell">
    <li aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-bell-slash-o"></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="error-message-list">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inner-container{margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;}
.error-message-container .error-message-bell {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;}
.error-message-container .error-message-list {
    display: table-cell;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding-left: 8px;}
```